# simple springboot not work on aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i create a elastistic benstalk with sample default project and works ok, but after i upload my spring boot project and it not work, but work well on localhost.
for check erros better i do a very simple spring boot project, only with web dependencies and one simple endpoint, but not work yet

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

i create only this class

```
package com.example.demo.Testing;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestingAWS {

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> sayOk(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and the @SpringBootApplication

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    } }
```

i try run with no config in application.properties and with:

```
server.port=8080
```

i gerenate war using

```
mvn clean install
```

and after `mvn spring-boot:run` to deploy on localhost and work well, the endpoint return status 200

but i give this erros in console

```
2018-04-18 16:30:55.468  INFO 19224 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-04-18 16:30:55.469  INFO 19224 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

and this application not work on aws. log of error:

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-770207322946.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-vnewtwgp2g/i-0f4edca74953a1e67/TailLogs-1524080692420.out?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOUOORMVUTXOJUHQ&Expires=1524167093&Signature=RILCgkY%2B0pJqEgnHNooejNEa9NU%3D

i put a link because is very large and stackoverflow say i exced caracteres limit

but in health say server is ok

[image]

but if a try do a request i get this error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.12.1</center>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
2018-04-18 16:30:55.468  INFO 19224 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-04-18 16:30:55.469  INFO 19224 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

Is not an error. This means that Spring Boot are registering a controller with the endpoint `/error`. Is the default behavior of Spring Boot, as explained [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-application-configuration):

> Spring Boot automatically registers a BasicErrorController bean if you
>   don’t specify any custom implementation in the configuration.

You can also see that the log level is `INFO`, not `ERROR`.

Probably, the Spring Boot is not the cause of the error 502 Bad Gateway. There are many causes for this error. I suggest to you to create another question with the focus on your AWS setup.

Comment: You are the best, i m was all day try do it, i never think of it is a configuration aws problem. i change port to 5000 and problem solved. the solution are here: https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-elas
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the @SpringBootApplication?

Did you tryied to replace the ? for String on the method just to see if it is generating the problem?

If you just want to return the HttpStatus maybe you should change your method to:

```
public HttpStatus sayOk(){
   return HttpStatus.ok;
}
```

Comment: the @SpringBootApplication was created automatic, i edit my answer
i will try with string to see

Comment: using return string not work too and not showing not more